# Поиск слова в тексте

Tags: swift, строки

Есть переменная A с текстом, и переменная B со словом, подскажите как проверить текст A на наличее слова B в нем. Именно на языке Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Если просто наличие подстроки используйте метод String:

```
a.contains(b)
```